# Apache: Redirect requests where ServerName doesn't match

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm relatively new to Apache rewrite rules. What I need to do I think should be relatively easy, but I could use a bit of help.

I have a number of name based virtual hosts defined in my Apache configs, for developers to test new feature branches, and I have a wildcard DNS CNAME setup to direct traffic.

Everything works as it should when a request matches the ServerName in one of the virtual hosts. However if the hostname in the request doesn't match any explicitly defined virtual hosts, it automatically uses the first virtual host.

This is quite confusing, as a developer may think they're accessing the correct virtual host, when in fact they're not.

What I'd like to do, is define a rewrite rule in the first virtual host, so that if the hostname in the request doesn't exactly match the defined "ServerName", it will redirect it.

For example...

If I have 2 virtual hosts defined like so...

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName default.mydomain.com
    ...

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName my-feature-1.mydomain.com
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

and a developer is trying to request the site for their new feature, but spell it incorrectly, i.e.

https://feature-1.mydomain.com

The first virtualhost will silently serve the request, and they may be none the wiser, and wonder why their new feature code appears not to be working.

What I would like it to do instead. I'd like to redirect them to...

https://default.mydomain.com

so that it's obvious they've misstyped the URL.

Comment: The virtual hosts are dynamically generated from git branches, so the hostnames could be anything. I need a generic way to do it.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. See e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host have _one_ vhost that is static and the catchall, and define your dynamic ones after that.

Comment: Thanks @AD7six I understand now. I've got it working as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it to work with the following rewrite rule in the first virtual host...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   "!^default\.mydomain\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         https://default.mydomain.com [L,NE,R=301]
```

This works as the default for any request not explicitly matched by the subsequent dynamic virtual hosts but also redirects to the preferred default URL. I don't want to actually serve any content on undefined URL's.

The only thing that would improve it slightly would be to not have to duplicate the domain name in the rules.